How to generate .jmx file for ADF pipeline
Recently I want to do load testing  for my azure data factory pipelines.
Now, I follow the document Load test a website by using a JMeter script in Azure Load Testing：
But the question is that:

This is for website, does it also apply to ADF pipeline?

The documentation only mentions uploading the JMeter test script .jmx file, but how is this file generated? The prerequisites mention sample, but which one is applicable to ADF? Do I need to modify it?

If the steps to generate .jmx are complicated, could you provide more precise reference documentation? I searched all over Google, but I still know nothing about it.



JMeter .jmx script is basically an XML file describing your JMeter test plan.
If you need to "generate" it:

Download and install JMeter
Open JMeter GUI
Either build your test plan manually, I guess you will need a  HTTP Request sampler to trigger the ADF pipeline via API or record it using your browser (or other application) and HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
Save the test script - it will be the "generated" .jmx file

The page you've referenced contains a link to some sample .jmx test script

Thanks for your quick answer, I will try your suggestion tomorrow.
